# jQuery Armazenar um item por vez

Tags: html, ajax

Tenho seguinte código.

- Existem várias opções
- Mas apenas uma opção eu gostaria de desagendar
- Clico em uma para verificar depois em outra
- Finalmente quando achar a opção que eu quero, entao clicar no botao "Desagendar"
- E desagendar somente onde eu cliquei

> **O problema:**

Se eu clicar em outras opções anteriores, e for finalmente clicar em desagendar, ele armazena todos os anteriores, executa todos os outros codigos

Eu gostaria de que ele executasse somente o atual.

Tipo ele exclui as outras opções também.

```js
 function cardapio(codigo){
    $('#cardapioModal').modal();
    $('.btn-desagenda').on('click',function(){
         alert(codigo);
    });
                 
  }
```

```html
  
    


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="cardapioModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="title-card"></span></h4>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="modal-body">
                    <p><span class="texto-cardapio"></span></p>
                </div>-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-desagenda" data-dismiss="modal">Desagendar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-close" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        
        
    </div>

    <table border='1'>
       <tr>
         <td><a href='#' onclick="cardapio(1)">01/01/2017</a></td>
         <td>Cardapio 1</td>                  
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><a href='#' onclick="cardapio(2)">02/01/2017</a></td>
         <td>Cardapio 2</td>                  
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><a href='#' onclick="cardapio(3)">03/01/2017</a></td>
         <td>Cardapio 3</td>                  
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está com algum problema na inicialização da var 'codigo'.

Isto aqui funciona, porém vale lembrar que variaveis globais não são recomendadas  :

`var x = 0;
function cardapio(cod){
  x = cod;
  $('#cardapioModal').modal();

}
$('.btn-desagenda').click(function(){
    alert(x);
});`

Inicializando a cada chamada o valor de 'x', você não terá problema, porém ainda não sei te explicar o porque do seu código não zerar o valor sozinho a cada chamada. Mas espero que te ajude.